# .NET Solution Viewer

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know of a program which works like a Adobe PDF Reader except for .NET solutions?

I develop in a virtual machine but there are times when I just want to open a solution and browse the files.  I have no intention of doing any development, I just want to view them.

Does this app exist, or is Notepad++ my best option?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the reason behind *not* using Visual Studio?

Comment: @routeNpingme: I don't want to have four or five of them open, just to look at code.  I just want to look at my source, I guess Notepad++ is my option.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider making a simple XSL Transform that can read the SLN and create pretty little list of files for you.. if that's what you mean, otherwise the XML is probably the best you are going to get.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of a "solution reader."  When viewing source files on a system without VS.NET I use Notepad.